# Closed form of $ S = \sum_{n=1}^{99} \frac{(5)^{100}}{(25)^{n} + (5)^{100}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$ S =  \sum_{n=1}^{99} \frac{(5)^{100}}{(25)^{n} + (5)^{100}}$$

I tried writing first and end terms to make a similar face in the denominator, but in vain. The denominators are getting same in alternate terms.
I tried adding and subtracting by 1 to look after a v(n) and v(n-1) pair of terms also, but that just isn't anywhere near.

Comment: You can enclose MathJax in `$$` as opposed to `$` to automatically render it display style

Comment: I just started using StackExchange Mobile. So it's a bit difficult for me to make up with MathJax after using the UI for most of the time. But yeah, I will get used to that.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$f(n)=\dfrac{a^m}{a^n+a^m}$$

$$f(2m-n)=\dfrac{a^m}{a^{2m-n}+a^m}=\dfrac1{a^{m-n}+1}=\dfrac{a^n}{a^m+a^n}=1-f(n)$$

Here $2m=100,a=25$

Set $m=1,50$ and add

Comment: @Idle, Please find the updated answer.

Comment: nice twist ....

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{q + 1} + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{q}+1} =\  ?$$